# What calls your custom service host factory in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

So I am new to WCF and I have managed to get a custom ServiceHostFactory working in WCF and when I put a break point in the CreateServiceHost method and look at the call stack it says it was called by external code. It isn't that important but just for the sake of trying to work through the fog - What is that external code?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you hosting your WCF service??

Either you're **self-hosting**, e.g. you have a command-line or NT Service app - but in that case, you yourself need to create the `ServiceHost`.

The other option would be **hosting in IIS/WAS**, and in that case, the IIS/WAS will listen for incoming requests, and those for a `*.svc` file (your service file) will be captured. When such a request request comes in, the IIS/WAS runtime will instantiate your WCF service host for you. That part would be the *external code* that you probably see in your call stack

Comment: Yeah, thanks - I created a WCF Service app so IIS is hosting it. Thanks - it just gives me some perspective.